# Thread 1: EXC_BAD INSTRUCTION with NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, nsuserdefaults

I have it so that when my game ends, it switches to a separate SKScene which shows the new high score. Here is my code:

```
   func saveState() {

     let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setInteger(highScore, forKey: "labelScore") //this line says "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value
    defaults.setInteger(stars, forKey: "SNOW")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
```

What could be nil? I have values for everything in this function. Will post more code if necessary.

Comment: highscore it is probably nil. just use guard let highscore = highscore else { return }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that it was probably saved wrong to begin with. I would recommend using constants for things such as accessing user defaults so that this type of thing doesn't happen.

EDIT:

What I usually do is create a separate file that is a global constants file as part of a struct
In this file you can define constants like so:

```
struct GlobalConstants {
    static let defaultsHighScore = "labelScore"
}
```

Then, when I try to read from defaults, instead of typing in everything every time, I can just use the constant like this: `defaults.setInteger(highScore, forKey: GlobalConstants.defaultsHighScore)`

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you mean please?

Comment: I will give this a shot! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome! Also note that as of iOS 8, Apple recommends that you no longer synchronize defaults after updating them. If you find this works for you please up vote my answer :)